# HList with DataKinds, kind not promotable

Tags: haskell, gadt, type-families, data-kinds, constraint-kinds

I have this code snippet which uses a plethora of GHC extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

data HList :: [*] -> * where
    Nil  :: HList '[]
    Cons :: a -> HList l -> HList (a ': l)

type family All (p :: * -> Constraint) (xs :: HList [*]) :: Constraint where
    All p Nil = ()
    All p (Cons x xs) = (p x, All p xs)
```

GHC complains that:

```
 ‘HList’ of kind ‘[*] -> *’ is not promotable
    In the kind ‘HList [*]’
```

Why can't I promote `HList` to a kind? I get the same error using GHC `7.8.2` and `7.11`.

Of course, using the builtin `'[]` works just fine:

```
type family All (p :: * -> Constraint) (xs :: [*]) :: Constraint where
    All p '[]       = ()
    All p (x ': xs) = (p x, All p xs)
```

I want to use my own `HList` instead of `'[]` because the actual `HList` supports appending and looks like this:

```
type family (:++:) (xs :: [*]) (ys :: [*]) where
    '[] :++:  ys = ys
     xs :++: '[] = xs
    (x ': xs) :++: ys = x ': (xs :++: ys)

data HList :: [*] -> * where
    Nil  :: HList '[]
    Cons :: a -> HList l -> HList (a ': l)
    App  :: Hlist a -> HList b -> HList (a :++: b)
```

**EDIT**: The main goal is to have GHC infer

```
(All p xs, All p ys) ==> All p (xs :++: ys)
```

so that I can write

```
data Dict :: Constraint -> * where
    Dict :: c => Dict c

witness :: Dict (All p xs) -> Dict (All p ys) -> Dict (All p (xs :++: ys))
witness Dict Dict = Dict
```

I had hoped that adding an explicit representation for appending type-level lists would help me achieve this. Is there another way to convince GHC of the above?

Comment: Why do you need `All` to be on `HList`? Any time you need it, you can just use `All` on the `[*]` that is the type argument of your `HList`, i.e. you can have `frobulate :: All (Frobable xs) => HList xs -> Frob`

Comment: You can't promote GADTs because GHCs type system (or, more like kind system) simply doesn't support it. Your second HList doesn't particularly make sense, because every list has multiple representations, and you can't pattern match on `:++:` anyways. I'm guessing you want to eventually write something like `All p (xs :++: ys) = All p xs :++: All p ys`, but that won't work.  Is there an actual problem you are trying to solve with your 2nd HList?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to promote HList to kind.  Why can't you do with `'[]` ? You can easily append '`[]`'.

Comment: @user2407038: Thanks for the helpful info. You're exactly correct, I want to be able to convince GHC `(All p xs, All p ys) => All p (xs :++: ys) => ...` and I hoped that adding an explicit representation for appending would help. The more I think about your comment, I start to see some of the issues that you mention (lack of a unique representation). Is there any other way for me to prove `(All p xs, All p ys) => All p (xs :++: ys)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see now that the question is how to write a proof of `(All p xs, All p ys) => All p (xs :++: ys)`. The answer is, by induction, of course!

The type of the function we really want to write is

```
allAppend :: (p :: Constraint) -> (xs :: [*]) -> (ys :: [*]) 
          -> (All p xs, All p ys) -> All p (xs :++: ys)
```

but Haskell doesn't have dependent types. "Faking" dependent types usually means having a witness that carries a proof that a type exists. This makes things somewhat tedious, but currently there is no other way. We already have a witness for a list `xs` - it is precisely `HList xs`. For constraints, we will use

```
data Dict p where Dict :: p => Dict p
```

Then we can write implication as a simple function:

```
type (==>) a b = Dict a -> Dict b
```

So our type becomes:

```
allAppend :: Proxy p -> HList xs -> HList ys 
          -> (All p xs, All p ys) ==> (All p (xs :++: ys))
```

The body of the function is quite straightforward - note how each pattern in `allAppend` matches each pattern in the definition of `:++:`:

```
allAppend _ Nil _  Dict = Dict  
allAppend _ _  Nil Dict = Dict 
allAppend p (Cons _ xs) ys@(Cons _ _) Dict = 
  case allAppend p xs ys Dict of Dict -> Dict
```

The opposite entailment `All p (xs :++: ys) => (All p xs, All p ys)` also holds. In fact, the function definition is identical.

Comment: This looks promising. I had tried a "fake dependent types" approach but got stuck. I'll update this thread when I get a chance to try your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: You've answered my original question and `allAppend` works as advertised. I think it's sent me down the right track. Unfortunately I've hit some snags related to other related code that I didn't include in my original question. I may open another SO question related to this one